# Count column string in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
+-------------+
|       fruits|
+-------------+
|        apple|
|       orange|
|jack | banana|
|       cherry|
+-------------+
```

How to find a fruits count?

Result should be 5.

How to replace `|` and split the jack and banana?

Comment: What did you try @Ponnan Shankar?

Comment: A combination of `split` and `size` (both from `functions`) followed by an aggregate with `sum` should do the trick.

Comment: could you help me with code ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say exploding "jack | banana" into 2 rows is the tricky part.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val fruits : DataFrame =
  ???

// you'll explode "jack | banana" into 2 different rows
def explodeFruits(col: Column): Column =
  explode(split(col, " | "))

fruits
  .select(explodeFruits(col("fruits")))
  .count
```

Comment: val result = join1.select(
                       explode(split(col("fruits"), " | ")).as("fruits")
                    )
                    .filter(col("fruits") !== "|")
                    .count()
                    
      println("approx_count_distinct: "+result )

Comment: yes gatear. its working as expected

Comment: then don't forget to vote and mark the correct answer